# Laravel 5 Eventing For UserRegistering

Tags: laravel, event-handling, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out why I'm not getting any feedback when I'm trying to call my event of the user being registered. The other parts of the store function work just fine however it doesn't give me any errors in my log or anything when trying to debug. I have my MAIL_DRIVER set to log in my .env file so I'm not getting anything returned.

Anyone know why?

**app/Events/UserWasRegistrered.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\UserAccount;

class UserWasRegistered extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $userAccount;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param UserAccount $user
     */
    public function __construct(UserAccount $userAccount)
    {
        $this->userAccount = $userAccount;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**app/Listeners/SendRegistrationEmail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Mailers\AppMailer;

class SendRegistrationEmail
{
     protected $mailer;        

     /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     */
    public function __construct(AppMailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserWasRegistered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserWasRegistered $event)
    {
        $this->mailer->sendWelcomeEmailTo($event->user->email);
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/UserAccountsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UserAccount;
use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;
use App\Http\Requests\UserAccountCreatedPostRequest;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserAccountsController extends Controller
{

     /**
     * Stores the user account saved in the create form to the database.
     *
     * @param UserAccountCreatedPostRequest $request
     * @param UserAccount $userAccount
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(UserAccountCreatedPostRequest $request, UserAccount $userAccount)
    {
        $userAccountCreated = $userAccount->create($request->all());

        event(new UserWasRegistered($userAccountCreated));

        if ($userAccountCreated) {
            flash()->success('Success', 'The user account has been successfully created!');
        } else {
            flash()->error('Error', 'The user account could not be successfully created!');
        }

        return redirect()->to(route('app.user-accounts.index'));
    }
}
```

app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\UserWasRegistered' => [
            'App\Listeners\SendRegistrationEmail',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        //
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For some reason with the following I'm getting the following error.

*FatalThrowableError in AppMailer.php line 35: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mailers\AppMailer::sendWelcomeEmailTo() must be an instance of App\Mailers\UserAccount, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Projects/repositories/myapp/app/Listeners/SendRegistrationEmail.php on line 31*

app\Listeners\SendRegistrationEmail

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Mailers\AppMailer;

class SendRegistrationEmail
{
    protected $mailer;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     */
    public function __construct(AppMailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserWasRegistered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserWasRegistered $event)
    {
        $this->mailer->sendWelcomeEmailTo($event->userAccount->email);
    }
}
```

Comment: before firing the event what do you see if you dd($userAccountCreated) ?

Comment: The UserAccount object.

Comment: Everything looks ok. var_dump will not show you anything though. Did you try sending an email or logging to a file?

Comment: Yeah I have my mail setup in the .env file as being logged as explained in the top.

Comment: I understand your email setup but you don't send an email in your handle function.

Comment: But if var_dumping isn't doing anything then I know an email won't be sent. I was going to change that once I knew the var_dump would show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106118/discussion-between-user3732216-and-can-celik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the third answer for the different questions you have asked.

Looking at the error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Mailers\AppMailer::sendWelcomeEmailTo() must
be an instance of App\Mailers\UserAccount, string given
```

You need to pass the the user account instead of just email as follows:

```
$this->mailer->sendWelcomeEmailTo($event->userAccount);
```

Comment: Okay I apologize. I keep coming up with errors as its not working. I am now receiving: FatalThrowableError in AppMailer.php line 35: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mailers\AppMailer::sendWelcomeEmailTo() must be an instance of App\Mailers\UserAccount, instance of App\UserAccount given, called in /home/vagrant/Projects/repositories/myapp/app/Listeners/SendRegistrationEmail.php on line 31

Comment: You can see in the error message, it says type error. You are passing wrong instance to sendWelcomeEmailTo() function or sendWelcomeEmailTo is not expecting the right instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need register the listener

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#registering-events-and-listeners

In the file `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` fill the attribute `$listen`

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserWasRegistered' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendRegistrationEmail',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to include that in my post so I updated it. This was something I already had in place. So that is not the issue.

Comment: So, I don't know what is wrong, everything looks right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Change your app/Listeners/SendRegistrationEmail.php to below so it sends an email (or logs in your case)

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UserWasRegistered;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Mail;

class SendRegistrationEmail
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserWasRegistered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserWasRegistered $event)
    {

        Mail::raw('You have been successfully registered to the site', function ($message) use ($event) {
            $message->to($event->userAccount->email);
            $message->subject('Welcome');
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post and the issue is this: Undefined property: App\Events\UserWasRegistered::$user

Comment: are you still having an issue?

Comment: Yes because I'm getting the error in the above comment

Comment: Just updated the code. It should be $event->userAccount->email not $event->user->email.

Answer (score 0):

Try dd() instead of var_dump() to see if it's working.

Comment: Hmm not sure why this gets downvote but it was actually the solution to one of the issues here.